# xsl:namespace-alias does not work as expected while using xsl:copy-of

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a requirement where i have to remove soap envelope from the request payload and change namespace of the parent tag from namespace `"random.com/system/i/Modify/1.0"` to `"http://random.com/G/Modify"`, request header from namespace `"http://random.com/2/MsgHeader/"` to `"http://random.com/3/MsgHeader/"` and request body namespace `"http://random.com/2/MsgBody/"` to `"http://random.com/3/MsgBody/"`

I am not sure why `xsl:namespace-alias` is not able to change the namespaces properly

Transformation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
version="3.0"
exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv"
xmlns:old="random.com/system/i/Modify/1.0/"
xmlns:gcp="http://random.com/G/Modify"
xmlns:ogcph="http://random.com/2/MsgHeader/"
xmlns:hgcph="http://random.com/3/MsgHeader/"
xmlns:ogcpb="http://random.com/2/MsgBody/"
xmlns:hgcpb="http://random.com/3/MsgBody/">


<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="soapenv" result-prefix="#default"/> 
<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="old"     result-prefix="gcp"/>
<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="ogcph"    result-prefix="hgcph"/>
<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="ogcpb"    result-prefix="hgcpb"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <gcp:Modifys>  
    <gcp:Modify>
        <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:Modifys/*:Modify/*"/>
    </gcp:Modify>
  </gcp:Modifys>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How do you "expect" namespace-alias to work? It allows you to create result elements in a certain namespace in your  XSLT code to be later mapped to the result namespace, it doesn't help to change the namespace of input nodes.

Comment: How should I change namespace of the input nodes then?

Comment: Write templates like `<xsl:template match="old:*"><xsl:element name="gcp:{local-name()}" namespace="http://random.com/G/Modify"><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/><xsl:template>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked the same question here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4817

and this was my answer:

*If you read the spec for xsl:namespace-alias you will see that it only affects literal result elements.
If you want to copy elements with a change of namespace, use a template rule such as*

```
<xsl:template match=xyz:"*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://new-namespace/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Please don't make extra effort for people by asking the same question in several different forums.